# Passing Drawables between Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-drawable

I am trying to pass a drawable between activities. I am unsure as to whether I can just get a drawables resourceID from an alertdialog and pass that value as an Int to another activity.

I have explored changing the drawable to a bitmap, and I have also tried getResources().getIdentifier() but perhaps I was using them incorrectly.

**What should I do to pass a drawable between activities using .putExtras(bundle)**

```
public class CreateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etTitle;
Button btDate;
Button btTime;
Button btPic;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    //onclicklistener
    findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_back).setOnClickListener(this);

    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
    btPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_picture);

}

// Will be called via the onClick attribute
// of the buttons in main.xml
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_confirm:
        String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
        String time = btTime.getText().toString();
        String date = btDate.getText().toString();

        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.btn_picture);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

        Log.e("LOG", title);
        Log.e("LOG", time);
        Log.e("LOG", date);

        Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
        newBundle.putString("TITLE", title);
        newBundle.putString("TIME", time);
        newBundle.putString("DATE", date);

        //Trying to pass a drawable from one activity to another
        newBundle.putParcelable("BITMAP", bitmap);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(newBundle);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();

        break;

    case R.id.btn_back:
        finish();
        break;
    }

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void showPicturePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new PicturePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "picturePicker");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you pass the identifier, which is just an integer. Rebuild the drawable as needed in the next activity.

```
intent.putIntExtra(DRAWABLE_KEY, R.id.your_drawable_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as its staying inside the same apk, I'd just transfer the id of the drawable (R.id.btn_picture) as an int, since all services/activities can grab resources.